# character comparison between string

Tags: java

my goal is to write the method which check whether any letter from string 1 (letters) exists on the string 2 (password) and if yes replace it with "X"

```
    public String hiddenWord() {

        String password = "abcde";
        String letters = "ad";
        String empty = "";  

        for(int i =0; i <= password.length()-1; i++){
            if(letters.contains(password.substring(i))){
                empty += password.substring(i); 
            }else{
                empty += "X";
            }
        }
        return empty;
    }
```

Could you please piont me a issue? program return me result "XXXXX"

Comment: ok done! Incorrectly used substring

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i <= password.length()-1; i++){
       char f = password.charAt(i);
       String r = String.valueOf(f);
       if(letters.contains(r)){
        empty += password.charAt(i);
       }else{
        empty += "X";
       }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In your logic, you are comparing the whole string**, rather you need to check each character by character as shown in the below code with comments:

```
public static String hiddenWord() {
        String password = "abcde";
        String letters = "ab";
        StringBuilder empty = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i <= password.length() - 1; i++) {
           //check character is found and replace with X
           if(i<letters.length() && letters.charAt(i) == password.charAt(i)) {
                empty.append("X");
           } 
           //otherwise keep the same character
           else if(i<letters.length() && letters.charAt(i)!= password.charAt(i)){
                empty.append(password.charAt(i));
          }
        }
        return empty.toString();
    }
```

Alternatively, you can achieve the same result by using `String` API's `replace()` method as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
String password = "abcde";
String letters = "ad";
String empty = password;  

for(int i =0; i <= letters.length()-1; i++){
    empty = empty.replace(letters.charAt(i), 'X');
}
System.out.println(empty);
```

You don't need complex logic to check, replace and append the characters. Simple string `replace` method call will do.